# What size should the icon in an alertdialog be?

Tags: java, android, icons, android-alertdialog

I am trying to assign an icon to an alertdialog but keep getting a memory error (seems to be from the size of the icon).

What size should the icon be for an alertdialog?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

32x32 at mdpi. See [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/icon_design_dialog.html). Very easy to google.

Comment: It doesn't actually say that on the page you link to, in fact it is frustratingly vague about Dialog icons. You are right though: in the Android source ic_dialog_alert.png is 32x32 at MDPI.

Comment: try using 48x48 dip, 32 results blur image

Comment: @Zyoo, that's not enough information. What device are you on? What resolution? Are you providing alternate assets for different resolution buckets?

Comment: they all seem blur to me, but if I provide 48x48, it's still blur but with bigger icon on screen (sorry don't take my advice, stay with 32dp)

Comment: You're doing something wrong and/or scaling the icons to the bounds of your `ImageView`. What size (in dp) did you set for that?

Comment: To be more precise: 32dp

Comment: @MarkCarter, I wouldn't say this is more precise. The question was what the size of the icon (asset) should be for an alert dialog. That's 32x32 pixels at mdpi. That translates to 32dp -- but that wasn't the question ;)

Comment: @323go DIP is also a size measurement. The OP does not specify whether the measurements should be in pixels or dips (or inches for that matter). DIP works across all screen densities so does not require the reader to look up what a specific screen density means. Almost no devices these days use MDPI, so a developer could be forgiven for not realising MDPI is 1x. Click on the icons here and you will see all the measurements are in DP: https://design.google.com/icons/

Answer (score 3):

Most Internet results will lead you that HDPI is the max icon you need. This is WRONG.

Just tested as a part of the current project and this is what get you the best result:

LDPI 24px
MDPI 32px
HDPI 48px
XHDPI 64px
XXHDPI 96px
XXXHDPI 128px